# (Laravel) Real time Search in Pre-Fetched Database Data

Tags: javascript, database, laravel, search

So I have this database with several columns. Let's assume that I have a *view* where I show certain pre-fetched database columns and display them with a *foreach* loop inside a *div*.

What I want to do is to be able to have a search bar in that same *view* which will update that *div's* content in real-time (without pressing enter or a button) to only show the results that contain my search query.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thank you very much.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Tiago

Comment: What is the hard part? Finding a way to run a search? Searching? Populating the div without destroying the search bar? Filtering the results? All these? All these and some additional problems? Something else?

Comment: But most important, do you want to use React/Vue/Angular/Vanilla?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comments. I want to know how can I implement a system like typeahead.js fut instead of fetching directly from database, it would fetch from the pre-fetched content on that div.

Comment: So why not use typeahead itself?

Comment: We can't explain you how to implement an entire system. Please show what you have, and explain where you have stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use keyup Function in Jquery  using Ajax then it will show result realtime on key press

```
<input type="text" value="" id="dSuggest" />
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dSuggest").keyup(function() {
        var dInput = $(this).val();
        alert(dInput);

    });
});
```

Comment: How about those devices without a keyboard? What if I'll paste some text to the search bar? Or drop some text on the search bar?

Comment: Please Check this Link  , You can check in Network. Request is send on copy paste


https://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/32Bck/

Answer (score 0):

### You can do like that

```
<input type="text" placeholder="type something ..." id="suggest" />


$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#suggest").autocomplete({
        delay: 100,
        source: function (request, response) {

            // Suggest URL
            var suggestURL = "https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%QUERY";
            suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

            // JSONP Request
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                url: suggestURL
            })
            .success(function(data){
                response(data[1]);
            });
        }
    });

});
```